# Expanding in small but non zero quantity

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, series-expansion

I am trying to deal with a function which diverges at $r=0$. I encountered the following function

$$f(r)=\int_0^1\frac{x^2(2-x)}{1-x+rx^2}\mathrm dx$$

The paper says that in the limit $r\ll1$, it looks like

$$f(r)=-\ln(r)-7/6+O(r)$$

Is there any way to obtain this in *Mathematica*? Obviously `Limit` as $r$ approaches 0 is undefined. Integrating and using `Series` does not work for me.

Comment: The remark "Integrating and using Series does not work for me" should be accompanied by actual code, otherwise it is impossible to determine what has gone astray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Assumptions = 0 < r < 1/4;
Integrate[(x^2 (2 - x))/(1 - x + r x^2), {x, 0, 1}]
(* (1/(2 Sqrt[ 1 - 4 r] r^3))(-2 Sqrt[1 - 4 r] r + 3 Sqrt[1 - 4 r] r^2 +   4 r (-1 + 2 r) ArcTanh[1/Sqrt[1 - 4 r]] +   4 r (-1 + 2 r) ArcTanh[(-1 + 2 r)/Sqrt[1 - 4 r]] +   3 r Log[1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 r]] - 3 r Log[1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 r]] -   Log[(1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 r])/(1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 r])] -   3 r Log[1 - Sqrt[1 - 4 r] - 2 r] +   3 r Log[1 + Sqrt[1 - 4 r] - 2 r] - Sqrt[1 - 4 r] Log[r] +   3 Sqrt[1 - 4 r] r Log[r])*)

Series[%, {r, 0, 1}]
(* (-(7/6) - Log[r]) + (-(13/4) - 3 Log[r]) r + O[r]^2 *)
```

Comment: Assumptions actually made the job, thank you so much! Does $ indicates that these assumptions are global for the notebook?

Comment: @Markon Yes. Cheers!

Comment: @Markon, you can use `Assuming[]` instead if you want a less drastic route.

Comment: ... or use `Assumptions -> ...`

Comment: I cannot reproduce these results with v11.2 on a Mac. I get the error message "SeriesData::slnc: Argument O[r]^2 in Log is a series with no coefficients." along with `Log[SeriesData[r, 0, {}, 2, 2, 1]]*
     SeriesData[r, 0, {-3/2}, -2, -1, 1] + SeriesData[r, 0, 
     {(3*(Log[2] + 2*Log[r]))/2}, -2,  -1, 1]`

Comment: @BobHanlon that's... weird. The `Integral` part or the `Series` part? Either way, perhaps it should be reported to the WA team.